# Thispagestyle won't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, fancyhdr

Currently I have a "random" page in my document and I wanted to insert here some tikz-graphic. If I use my usual pagestyle the tikz graphic overlays with my headers, so I wanted to deactivate them with \thispagestyle{empty} but it will not work.

```
\usepackage[a4paper,            % Papierformat A4
    left=2.5cm,             % linker Rand
    right=2.5cm,            % rechter Rand
    top=1.5cm,              % oberer Rand
    bottom=1.5cm,           % unter Rand
    marginparsep=5mm,       % Abstand der Randnotizen
    marginparwidth=10mm,    % Breite der Randnotizen
    headheight=7mm,         % Hoehe der Kopfzeile
    headsep=1.2cm,          % Abstand der Kopfzeile
    footskip=1.5cm,         % Abstand der Fusszeile
    includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}                       % Konfiguration von Kopf- und Fusszeilen
\pagestyle{fancy}                           % Seitenstil 'fancy'
\fancyhf{}                                  % vorhandene Einstellungen loeschen
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}          % Kopf- und Fusszeile so breit wie der Haupttext
\fancyfoot[L]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\thepage}{\leftmark}}   % Festlegung des Seitenstils: Seitenzahlen in der Fusszeile rechts
\fancyfoot[R]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\leftmark}{\thepage}}   % Kapitelnr. und -Bezeichnung in der Fusszeile links
\fancyhead[R]{\IhreArbeit}                  % "Bachelorarbeit" in der Kopfzeile rechts
\fancyhead[L]{\IhrVorname\ \IhrNachname}    % Vorname und Name in der Kopfzeile links
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{         % Definition der Ausgabe des Kapitels
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{}{\clearpage}\markboth{Kapitel \thechapter. #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}        % Trennlinie zwischen Kopfzeile und Haupttext
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}        % Trennlinie zwischen Haupttext und Fusszeile
\fancypagestyle{plain}{                 % Anpassung des Seitenstils 'plain' bei Beginn neuer Kapitel
    \fancyhf{}                              % Vorbelegung loeschen
    \fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}                 % Seitenzeilen in der Fusszeile mittig
    \fancyfoot[R]{\leftmark}                    % Seitenzeilen in der Fusszeile mittig
    \fancyhead[R]{\IhreArbeit}              % "Bachelorarbeit" in der Kopfzeile rechts
    \fancyhead[L]{\IhrVorname\ \IhrNachname}    % Vorname und Name in der Kopfzeile links
}
```

And some more packages are contained in my Master.tex
My chapters are in different source-files
Here the source-file where it is not working

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            box/.style={
                draw,
                minimum height=1cm,
                text width=4cm,
                fill=gray!20,
                align=center,
                node distance=0.5cm
                }
            ]

            %Lot of tikz that doesn't matter at this point
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{...}
    \end{figure}
\newpage
```

The result is the following 
[image]

Comment: it is very hard to answer unless you provide a usable example. Examples should be complete small documents so people can reproduce the problem. But probably your figure is on a float page (even though you have prevented it being placed on a float page by `[htb]`  it is too large to be placed on a text page so can not be placed anywhere so will go to the end of the document or the next `\clearpage` so the `\thispagestyle` does not affect the page the float is on.  use `\pagestyle{empty}` then use the float (with `[p]` then use `\pagestyle` to revert to your normal style

Comment: Sorry I thought this informations are enough. But anyway your answer was right - I forgot that my tikz was on a float-page. After deleting the figure-environment it worked perfectly.

I tried also your example but it was not like I wanted.
But I can live without a figure-environment or maybe I scale my tikz down so it will fit onto the page.

But thank you very much for the help with the float-page ! :)

Comment: May you can copy the solution as answer? - so I can set it as correct (Also I can't tag my answer as correct where I referenced to you)

Comment: no need, now you've posted an answer, just accept that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From David Carlisle

The tikz-graphic was on a float-page so the command `\thispagestyle{empty}` affected the wrong page. After deleting `\begin{figure}[htb]` it worked out fine.

As a second solution I size the tikz with the command `scale=0.8` down so it will fit onto the page